# Oracle- logically give each set of rows a group based on a value from ordered list

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this
[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47baf/1/0)

When ordered by the sequence_number field, these records need to be grouped and given a row_number based on the following logic:
All records for which the following line type is not a 0 is part of the same group.

Example, from the provided SQL fiddle,

sequence numbers 0,1 and 2 are part of the same group, and sequence numbers 3 and 4 are part of another group. Basically, any rows up to a 0 line type are part of a single group. The data I am trying to return will look like:

```
GROUP    LINE_TYPE    SEQUENCE_NUMBER    PRODUCT
------------------------------------------------
1        0            0                  REM322
1        6            1                  Discount
1        7            2                  Loyalty Discount
2        0            3                  RGM32
2        6            4                  Discount
```

Another way to re-word what I am after is that when ordered by the sequence number, the group number will change when it hit's a 0.

I've been racking my brain trying to think how to do this using partitions/lags and even self joins but am having trouble.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the column value to 1 if line_type is 0 and then calculate the running sum(using SUM as analytical function) over this.

```
select sum(case when line_type  = 0 then 1 
                else 0 end
          ) over (order by sequence_number) as grp,
       line_type,
       sequence_number,
       product
from ret_trand
order by sequence_number;
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47baf/2).

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing the grouping is using a hierarchical query and `CONNECT_BY_ROOT`:

```
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT sequence_number AS first_in_sequence,
       line_type,
       sequence_number,
       product
FROM   ret_trand
START WITH
       line_type = 0
CONNECT BY
       (    sequence_number - 1 = PRIOR sequence_number
        AND line_type <> 0)
ORDER SIBLINGS BY
       sequence_number;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47baf/15/0)

This will identify the groups by the initial sequence number of the group.

If you want to change this to a sequential ranking for the groups then you can use `DENSE_RANK` to do this:

```
WITH first_in_sequences AS
(
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT sequence_number AS first_in_sequence,
         line_type,
         sequence_number,
         product
  FROM   ret_trand
  START WITH
         line_type = 0
  CONNECT BY
         (    sequence_number - 1 = PRIOR sequence_number
          AND line_type <> 0)
  ORDER SIBLINGS BY
         sequence_number
)
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY first_in_sequence ) AS "group",
       line_type,
       sequence_number,
       product
FROM   first_in_sequences;
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/47baf/15/1)

Comment: Thankyou. Any idea which would be more efficient? The first solution works fine, although performance is terrible as it has to sort the results, although i guess any solution will have to. I'll try both and see which works best.

Comment: I've implemented this method and it works great..although performance is terrible :(, and that is with it using all indexes available.